# Adapting to the cold

Tags: survival, cold-weather

Some people seem to be able (as I've noticed when camping and traveling with different people) be able to produce more heat and need fewer layers in cold situations.  Are there any techniques that cold-weather campers and outdoors enthusiasts use to produce more body heat in for situations (for example, the Wim Hof method)?